# I have dry ran this implementation of tries with pair class but it's not giving expected output.What am i doing wrong?

Tags: c++, class, trie

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class trieNode{
public:
    int data;
    bool isTerminal;
    trieNode ** children;
    trieNode(int data){
        this->data = data;
        children = new trieNode*[26];
        for(int i=0;i<26;i++){
            children[i] = NULL;
        }
        isTerminal = false;
    }
};

class Pair{
public:
bool exist;
trieNode* address;
Pair(){
    exist = false;
    address = NULL;
}
};

class Trie{
public:
trieNode *root;

Trie(){
    root = new trieNode('\0');
}
// for programmer
private:
    void insert(trieNode* root,string word){
        //base case
        if(word.size() == 0){
            root->isTerminal = true;
            return ;
        }
        // small calculation
        int index = word[0] - 'a';
        trieNode *child;
        if(root->children[index] != NULL){
            child = root->children[index];
        }
        else{
            child = new trieNode(word[0]);
            root->children[index] = child;
        }

        // recursion
        insert(child,word.substr(1));

    }
    // for user
public:
void insertWord(string word){

    insert(root,word);
}
// for programmer
private:
void deleteWord(trieNode* root, string word){
    if(word.size() == 0){
        root->isTerminal = false;
        return;
    }
    int index = word[0] - 'a';
    trieNode *child;
    if(root->children[index] != NULL){
        child = root->children[index];
    }
    else{
        return;
    }
    deleteWord(child,word.substr(1));

    if(child->isTerminal == false){
        for(int i=0;i<26;i++){
            if(child->children[i] != NULL)
            return;
        }
        delete child;
        root->children[index] = NULL;
    }       
}
// delete word 
//for user
public:
void deleteWord(string word){
    deleteWord(root,word);
}
// search a sting in trie
//function for programmer
// i used a pair class as return type brcause i want to return if word exists then return it's 
address too
// i.e return a bool = true and adress where the word ends
private:
Pair find(trieNode *root, string word){
    Pair p;
    if(word.size() == 0){
        Pair p;
        p.address = root;
        if(root->isTerminal == true)
            p.exist = true;
        else
            p.exist = false;
        return p;
    }
    trieNode *child;
    int index = word[0]-'a';
    if(root->children[index] == NULL){
        Pair p;
        p.address = root;
        p.exist =  false;
        return p;
    }
    else{
        child = root->children[index];
        p = find(child, word.substr(1));
    }
}
// search a string in the trie
// function for user
public:
Pair findstr(string word){
Pair p;
p = find(root,word);
return p;
}
};

int main(){
Trie t;
t.insertWord("sucess");
t.insertWord("s");
t.insertWord("a");
Pair p;
p = t.findstr("sucess");
cout<< p.address->data <<" "<< p.exist<<endl;
p = t.findstr("s");
cout<< p.address->data <<" "<< p.exist<<endl; 
p = t.findstr("a");
cout<< p.address->data <<" "<< p.exist;
```

---

> I am using pair class for implementing a function called findstr which finds a word in the trie and returns 2 things a bool and address of the last trieNode of the word, for that i used a pair class, in this code it should return address in hexadecimal and true for all three , but i an only see garbage values

}

Comment: Now is the time to use the debugger and step through your program.  The debugger allows you to run your program one step at a time, where you can observe variables, watch the flow of the program, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem is here

```
else{
    child = root->children[index];
    p = find(child, word.substr(1));
}
```

that should be

```
else{
    child = root->children[index];
    p = find(child, word.substr(1));
    return p;
}
```

The compiler should have given you a warning about a missing return statement. Did you ignore it?

There may be many other problems with the code. As already said the thing to do is **use a debugger**. Much faster way to fix your bugs than ask on SO.